# Neo4J - Which is better to store element as a property of user or as a node & relationship?

Tags: neo4j, query-optimization, nodes

I got a problem when designing a graph model with million users. I need to store information that user is registered or non-register.
As I see we have 2 options:

1. Store a property "**register = true/false**" in each user node. So with 1 million user, we have 1 million properties "**register**".
2. Store a **Registered** node then make relationship just for registered user to this node. So we have number of relationship equal exactly with the registered user.

Which option is better in performance searching also about minimum storage?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how you plan to use this data in the future: specifically what kind of queries you want to make.

Comment: @stdob-- I want to know in list friend of user, who is registered and who is non-register. Of course, I have a relationship between each user who is friend. So I can find all friend of user before.

Comment: If for the `user` node this is a single simple value, without any additional attributes, it is more convenient to store it as a property of each node, and do not forget to create an index for it to speed up the search. If this is a complex fact (the time of registration, any additional data on the fact of registration, etc.), it makes sense to take it out to a separate node.

Comment: @stdob-- Maybe I need to store the time of registration, then it is better to take it out to a separate node. And I also find some information about sizing and hardware calculator on [link](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/)
it shows:
**Nodes occupy 15B of space, relationships occupy 31B of space and properties occupy 41B of space.**
So store relationships occupy less space than properties.

Comment: There is a 3rd option, you could add a :Registered label on the nodes. Typically label checks are less expensive than property reads.

Comment: @InverseFalcon true! I've edited my answer to include this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modeling your data as a graph is a difficult thing to pin down exactly. Typically, when it comes to NoSQL databases, the most important thing to consider is how you will be using your data, and to model it based on that.

Using the external node might run into performance problems, as Neo4J typically starts to run into issues during traversing as it approaches around 10,000 relationships in a single node. You will be well above that limit with an external "Registered" node; on the other hand as long as you are not anchoring your search to that node, it should be okay.

No matter which route you go, the query you described in the comments will likely anchor on (start with) the user, then traverse to who their friends are, and then for each friend, it will check whether it

A. has the "registered" property set to 'true'
B. has a relationship to the "Registered" node.

Each of these methods appears to have a similar execution time, and indexing on the "registered" property will have negligible impact because it is not being used as an anchor (presumably; you would have to `PROFILE` your query with both methods to find out for sure). So, like you mentioned, one might consider the space restraints.

Besides that, there is not much difference from a performance analysis perspective between the two methods that I can see.

A third option, mentioned by @InverseFalcon, is to use an additional label, ':Registered' on those nodes that are registered. This might well result in a faster comparison time than keeping it in a property, as labels will be inlined in the node store and can be checked there, whereas properties might have an additional level of indirection to the property store.

Comment: You mean a node can have more than 1 label? Currently these nodes have a label is :Person, because there will be many type of node in my graph. As third option, these nodes will have both :Person and :Registered label? It is ok on query?

Comment: And I also need to know time of registration. So I think separate a :Registered node and create a relationship with label: Register and property time in this relationship is more suitable.
Are there others option for this context?
Thank you.

Comment: @Alex yes, nodes absolutely can have more than one label. They are indexed automatically by label as well, so querying by label works fine. When querying, you do not need to give all labels; a single label would be sufficient (or none if it is not needed); e.g. (p:Person) is just as valid as (p:Person:Registered), although the second query may result in a scan of :Person nodes (engine would find all :Person nodes, than scan each for :Registered label). This is generally still faster than a scan for a particular value of a property, as InverseFalcon mentioned.

Comment: For what it's worth, if I needed to represent the date of registration, I would likely go with giving registered as a property that contains a date/timestamp and just leaving the unregistered ones without that property. Retrieving the properties on a relationship does not have poor performance, but if you want to filter (search) by a property on a relationship, it might not perform as well as a filter on the node itself. It depends on the exact query you are running, and I would again suggest that you `PROFILE` your queries liberally if tuning is a concern.